# why and when sys:incomplete aspect is getting applied for content in alfresco repository?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

I am migrating some contents from one alfresco 4.2 repository to other alfresco 5.2 repository using Apache chemistry Open CMSI API.

I am also migrating some metadata from Old repository along with content and adding it as a aspect in new repository.

But after migration one sys:incomplete aspect is getting applied for some contents.

Can anyone please explain the meaning of this aspect and why it is getting applied??

Because of this aspect I am getting some challenges for Advanced Search functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Refer this comment

> It is indeed the case that the 'sys:incomplete' aspect is not applied
>   if you "only" change the type of a node. The relevant policy
>   (IncompleteNodeTagger) is only triggered by node creation, property
>   updates, aspect updates, creation and deletion of (child)
>   associations. Unfortunately, changing the type is - as far as at the
>   moment - the only change to an object that does not trigger one of
>   these policies (apart from deletion, which is irrelevant for this use
>   case).
>   From this [question](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/202471-sysincomplete-aspect)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Your saying is write. I am creating a content in alfresco repository through CMIS API. So might be that time this aspect is getting applied.